# Error while installing tensorflow-rocm on arch linux?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, archlinux, arch

I just started to install tensorflow-rocm because i want to use my gpu in tensorflow.
System information:
OS: ARCH Linux
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series
RAM: 20GB

Python version: 3.11.3

`ERROR: /home/user/.cache/yay/tensorflow-rocm/src/tensorflow-2.12.0-rocm/tensorflow/compiler/xla/pjrt/BUILD:469:11: in cc_library rule //tensorflow/compiler/xla/pjrt:pjrt_future: target '@tf_runtime//:support' is not visible from target '//tensorflow/compiler/xla/pjrt:pjrt_future'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate ERROR: /home/user/.cache/yay/tensorflow-rocm/src/tensorflow-2.12.0-rocm/tensorflow/compiler/xla/pjrt/BUILD:469:11: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/compiler/xla/pjrt:pjrt_future' failed ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so' failed; build aborted: INFO: Elapsed time: 12.645s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (541 packages loaded\ , 23635 targets configured) currently loading: @arm_neon_2_x86_sse// ... (11 packages) ==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build(). Aborting... -> error making: tensorflow-rocm-exit status 4 checking dependencies...`

I just fixed some starting errors like, installing necessary dependencies. But here idk what should i do. Also i go to github and check issues about that but unfortunately i didn't found any solution.
git repo: https://github.com/rocm-arch/tensorflow-rocm